# Scrolling-Up after page was postback when I checked or unchecked the checkbox in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, updatepanel, autopostback

I have a **checkbox** in the bottom of my page that has a property of `Autopostback` that is set to **`true`**

When I checked or unchecked that **checkbox**, the scroll bar is going up instead of staying in it's current position, how to prevent this kind of problem in ASP.Net?

I search and try some solution but it is not working for me.. here is some of my solution that I do..

**I try this javascript.. but it is not effective..**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var xPos, yPos;
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();


        function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            if ($get('<%= Panel1.ClientID %>') != null) {
                xPos = $get('<%=Panel1.ClientID %>').scrollLeft;
                yPos = $get('<%=Panel1.ClientID %>').scrollTop;
            }
        }

        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            if ($get('<%= Panel1.ClientID %>') != null) {
                $get('<%=Panel1.ClientID %>').scrollLeft = xPos;
                $get('<%=Panel1.ClientID %>').scrollTop = yPos;
            }


        }
            prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
            prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
</script>
```

**even this... I put `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback`**

```
<%@ Page Title="Sample" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="sample.aspx.cs" Inherits="sample_Default" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" EnableViewState="true"%>
```

**and this..**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
        //some codes that is not important to my question...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a DIV before the Panel1 
as an ex:-

```
<div id="ItmeTypeDiv" style="width: 100%; height: 347px; overflow: auto" onscroll="javascript:document.getElementById('ItmeTypeDivScroll').value = this.scrollTop">

  YOUR PANEL
</div>
<asp:HiddenField ID="ItmeTypeDivScroll" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

in page load of the codebehind

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "LoadItemTypeScroll", "LoadItemTypeScroll();", true);
```

and this is a javascript you needto add

```
function LoadItemTypeScroll() {
try {
    document.getElementById('ItmeTypeDiv').scrollTop = document.getElementById('ItmeTypeDivScroll').value;
}
catch (e) { }
}
```